# Sending a setting data using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I open the settings using intent on Android studio. I would like to enter data in a part of these settings that are opened later. How can I do that?

After the object is submitted, the empty space (names, type, etc.) in the images must be filled Example Image

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yl6v.png)

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS");                              
startActivity(intent);
```

Like this :

An intent surrender.
A settings page opens.
I will send the variable with the intent.
I will place this variable on the settings page that opens.
For example, I will send "Recep" to the name field. When we initiate the intention, the name field will be filled with the name we sent.

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra("YOUR_VARIABLE", variable);
```

In your next activity you can get it with:

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_VARIABLE");
```

Comment: How do I write this on the phone when I go to another place like this? I am sending the data, but how do I get it on the other side

Comment: The next activity is not mine. Android settings activity. So how do I get there?

Comment: If you don't have the control of this dialog, I think that it's not possible. At least I don't know how to do it right now. Sorry.

Comment: No problem Thank you for try help :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send some variables with intent you can do it by put extra like this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstFragment.this, SecondFragment.class);

    //set variables like this
    intent.putExtra("FIRST_VARIABLE", first_value);
    intent.putExtra("SECOND_VARIABLE", second_value);
    startActivity(intent);

    //getting variables like this
    getIntent().getStringExtra("FIRST_VARIABLE");
    getIntent().getStringExtra("SECOND_VARIABLE");

    //set serializable object like this
    intent.putExtra(object_name, serializable_object);

    //get serializable object like this
    getIntent().getSerializableExtra(object_name);
```

and if you want to send object just implement your object Serializable and do like code in the top

Comment: Ty brother but Intent intent = new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS");                              
startActivity(intent);  After I wrote it, I opened it. For this reason, I do not know where to use the getIntent () method.

Comment: Oh. You are right. I will check it in the code and tell you if I find a way

Comment: @Meikem Thank you brother waiting for u :)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("yourValue", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get it SecondActivity class

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("yourValue");
```